# How to save tagged Template Literals in database

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

```
function vehicle(strings, type) {
    var wheels= "no";
    if(type === "car"){ wheels = 4;} 
    else if(type === "cycle"){ wheels = 2;} 
    return `${strings[0]}${wheels}${strings[1]}`;
}

var type = "car";
var output = vehicle`This vehicle has ${type} wheels.`;
console.log(output); //This vehicle has 4 wheels.
```

What's the best way to save `` "vehicle`This vehicle has ${type} wheels.`" `` in DB? I could do some string manipulations but wondering about better ways.

Comment: You cannot. Use some template engine.

Comment: If it's not a string written directly as JS code, it is by definition not a ["literal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)), unless you want to store arbitrary JS code in your DB and then `eval` it, which is horribly dangerous. As the other comment, says, don't do this. Instead your DB should hold string written in a template language.