How do I store a parametrized string in database?
My question is in the context of JavaScript.
Consider the object
{'name':`${name}`,'age':10}
My goal is to store this object in a database and then retrieve it in another session. The other session will have a variable name and the object should use that. How can I achieve that?
My idea was to store this object using JSON.stringify(). However that throws an error
Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined

Which makes sense.
But that's my goal. I want to store a parametrized string, which can be read from database, converted back to object using JSON.parse() and should use the name variable from that particular session.
How do I achieve that?

I suspect it would have to be stored as a regular string (not a template literal) and the formatting (token replacement) would be done manually when the time comes.

Don't think about it in terms of storing "JS objects". Instead you'll likely need to use a templating engine. Similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59229022/how-to-save-tagged-template-literals-in-database

There are a number of templating systems for JavaScript.

sounds like an XY problem.. you probably don't need to, use templating system as suggested, or describe your use case more

This question is similar to: Convert a string to a template string. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
